# Base 64 decoding in Android

Tags: android, encoding, base64, decoding

I have an Base 64 encoded string:
"MTg2MTYyOTAuMTQ5MTg1NzAxMy4a1x1biIm69KFEf6yYRztKIW745NNj+qzzDAQoEOiBYw=="

When I try to Base 64 decode this in Android it is giving some garbage characters.

Output : 18616290.1491857013.�[����D��G;J!n���c��(�c

Expected : 18616290.1491857013.[DG;J!nc(c

The code I am using is :

```
String val =new String(Base64.decode(encodedString,Base64.DEFAULT));
```

There are some garbage "?" characters getting introduced. How do I get rid of them ?

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure that you pass a UTF-8 string to your base-64 encoder. I suspect that the "garbage characters" are actually supposed to be there. Your pasted "expected" value has a "garbage character" between the `(` and the `c`, when I copy and paste it. And the base-64 encoding of that string is far shorter than the one in your question, based on [an online base-64 encoder](https://www.base64encode.org/).

Comment: Edited . Removed the garbage character from expected output.

Comment: A base-64 UTF-8 encoding of that output is `MTg2MTYyOTAuMTQ5MTg1NzAxMy5bREc7SiFuYyhj`, based on [this encoder](https://www.base64encode.org/). This is different -- and substantially shorter -- than what you have as the encoded value. Again, I think the problem is with your encoding, not with Andoid performing the decoding.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
private String decodeString(String encoded) {
    byte[] dataDec = Base64.decode(encoded.replace("=", ""), Base64.DEFAULT);
    String decodedString = "";
    try {

        decodedString = new String(dataDec, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {

        return decodedString;
    }
}
```

Comment: The solution indeed is specifying the charset of the original bytes in new String. Rather than UTF-8, that might be Cp1252 or whatever.